# Starting and stopping a server

Tags: server, tcl, tk-toolkit

So let's say I have a Tk interface with 2 buttons. I want one of them to start a server and one of them to close the server.
The code for the start button:

```
syslog "Server is Opened"
config

socket -server accept 12345 
vwait forever
```

What do I have to write in the stop button to stop this server? Or should starting and stopping the server happen in the same button, and how?

Comment: Stopping is simple: `set ::forever "now"`

Answer (score 1):

To shut down a server socket, you need to keep its handle around and `close` it when you no longer want it.

```
syslog "Server is Opened"
config

set number_of_connected_clients 0
set server [socket -server accept 12345]
vwait until_time_to_stop
close $server

# You probably want some extra time/code here to let clients disconnect gracefully
while {$number_of_connected_clients > 0} {
    vwait number_of_connected_clients
}
exit
```

Then you can trigger a shutdown by doing this (in a callback):

```
set ::until_time_to_stop "now, please"
```

The actual value you set the variable to is pretty arbitrary. The tricky part is that you *also* usually want to let any connected clients finish their business. To make the code above work, just increment the global `number_of_connected_clients` when a client connects (in the `accept` procedure probably) and decrement it again when you close your side of the client connection. There's other ways to achieve the same effect (e.g., by keeping client handles in a global array and `vwait`ing on that at the end with `[array size handles]` as the test) but it's just a variation on a theme.